# Communicate between my python library and ros

Tags: ros, python, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python class called primitive_surfaces that uses the script called primitive_shapes.py to find waypoints. Initially, I had a main that would instantiate an object of primitive_surfaces with required arguments and print out the waypoints.
I'm now planning to use this code and publish the variable waypoints using ROS. How can I communicate between non-ROS Python scripts and ROS?

Apologies if this question has been repeated many times, I'm fairly new to ROS and couldn't seem to find anything relevant.
Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227357/communicate-between-my-python-library-and-ros/) by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rospy inside of any python script as long as you have setup your ROS environment first.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0